# Time Difference in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a quiz and I want to calculate the time a user spends on a particular  section.I tried by calculating the difference between the page load time and the submit button click but as soon as the button is clicked the page refreshes(`AutoPostBack=true`) and the difference is zero. Is there a way I can calculate the time.

Below is the code for the following I am using.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtAlgebraLoad = DateTime.Now;
    lblTime.Text = dtAlgebraLoad.ToString();
}

protected void btnAlgebraNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtAlgebraNext = DateTime.Now;
    //timeSpan = dtAlgebraNext.Subtract(dtAlgebraLoad);
    Label1.Text = dtAlgebraNext.ToString();
    //Cal time duration between page and button Click
}
```

Comment: One way would be to store it in the user's session.

Comment: You should use Label1.Text = timeSpan.ToString() instead Label1.Text = dtAlgebraNext.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in Session but instead of that try to call javascript function on button click and implement the necessary logic in that function and bind the calculated difference to the label by using

> document.getElementbyId("Label1")

Answer (score 0):

Since web clients are very disconnected, I would store the Start Date/Time the user enters the section, then a LastActivity date on all subsequent calls when interacting with the section. This will allow you to see when the user last did something and when they started, giving you a duration, otherwise the duration may be left open ended.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JS solution to show the elapsed time (using jQuery to display it). Let this code run on page load. If you bind the result to an input tag, you can also post it back to the server.

The advantage is that the user always sees the currently elasped time.

```js
var start = new Date();

setInterval(function() {
    var msElapsed = new Date() - start;
    var dateObj = new Date(msElapsed);
    var elapsedTime = dateObj.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    $('#elapsedTimeDisplay').val(elapsedTime);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="elapsedTimeDisplay">Elapsed time:</label>
<input id="elapsedTimeDisplay" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden  field in aspx

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnStartTime">
```

I page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
   {
      hdnStartTime.Value = DateTime.Now;
   }
 }
```

Use `hdnStartTime.Value` to find difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
   {
      dtAlgebraLoad = DateTime.Now;
      lblTime.Text = dtAlgebraLoad.ToString();
   }
 }
```

Comment: That won't persist the value across multiple visits. If you declare `dtAlgebraLoad` as static it will, but then it'll be shared across users.

Comment: @Rob Rajan didn't decalre dtAlgebraLoad as static anywhere, so this answer is perfect.

Comment: @Imad Did you read the first part of my comment? If it's not static, it will *not* persist across page visits, which is what is required.